# Send a PHP variable to the DATE_ADD() SQL function?

Tags: php, mysql

I'd like to use a variable number of seconds ($seconds_to_add) in the DATE_ADD() function but it dosen't work. Is it possible ?

```
<?php
$requete = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE pages SET
    vote_time_limit =  DATE_ADD(vote_time_limit, INTERVAL :seconds_to_add SECOND)
    WHERE page_ID=:id_page');

$requete->bindValue(':id_page', $id_page);
$requete->bindValue(':seconds_to_add', $seconds_to_add);
```

Comment: how it `doesn't work` ? you have some debug messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind it as an int, because the default is a string (which includes quotes).

```
$requete->bindValue(':seconds_to_add', $seconds_to_add, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

I recommend you do it on the ID too.